# Matplotlib in C++

Tags: c++, matplotlib, fatal-error

I would like to use matplotlib to plot an x,y graph. To do this, I downloaded "matplotlibcpp.h" from github : https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp

However, in this file, there is an #include <Python.h> that was not found by the compiler. I solved this problem by downloading python (which contains this Python.h file) and entering the path to this file in the code blocks.

Then a similar error occurs again, but with #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>.

The problem is that this time, even with numpy installed, I can't identify this numpy/arrayobject.h file in my computer, so I can't add the path in code blocks.

Do you know where I can download this file, or how to solve this problem ? (I'm using Windows). I hope I have provide enough elements, please tell me if you need something else to answer this question.

Thank you very much !

NB: Despite searching for an answer in other topic-related questions, I have not managed to understand how to fix this problem (I am still a beginner with C++).

Comment: Did you follow the [instalation instructions](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp#user-content-installation)?

Answer (score 0):

After you install numpy, the header file should be in:
"""""your python dir""""\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include